# error occured when save data using hasmany relationnship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Create **hasmany** relatioship in **vehicle** model and insert data in vehicle and vehicle_staff table. data successfully insert in vehicle table but when store in vehicle_staff following error appear.

**Error Comes:**

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\collegeaccounting\app\Http\Controllers\Transport\VehicleController.php
>   on line 53

**Vehicle Staff Table Schema:**

```
Schema::create('vehicle_staffs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unsignedInteger('vehicles_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('staffs_id');

            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
        });
```

**Has Many Relationship on Vehicle Model:**

```
 class Vehicle extends BaseModel
{
    protected $fillable = ['created_by', 'last_updated_by', 'number', 'type', 'model', 'description', 'status'];

    public function staff(){
        return $this->hasMany(Staff::class);
    }
}
```

**Store Function:**

```
public function store(AddValidation $request)
    {
        $request->request->add(['created_by' => auth()->user()->id]);

        $vehicle =  Vehicle::create($request->all());

        if ($request->has('staffs_id')) {
            $staffs = [];
            foreach ($request->get('staffs_id') as $staff) {
                $staffs[$staff] = ([
                    'vehicles_id' => $vehicle->id,
                    'staffs_id' => $staff
                ]);
            }

            $vehicle->staff()->save($staffs);
        }

        $request->session()->flash($this->message_success, ' Created Successfully.');
        return redirect()->route($this->base_route);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are creating [many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), that is to say, a vehicle can belongs to many staffs, and a staff can have many vehicles. So, `vehicle_staffs` is a intermediate table (or pivot table) between `vehicle` model and `staff` model.

For **Vehicle** model, you should change the staff method to:

```
public function staff(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Staff::class, 'vehicle_staffs', 'vehicles_id', 'staffs_id');
}
```

To update [many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships), you can attach the staff ids to vehicle:

```
$vehicle->staff()->attach($staffIds);
```

and the code change of your store function:

```
if ($request->has('staffs_id')) {
    $staffIds = $request->get('staffs_id');
    $vehicle->staff()->attach($staffIds);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the pivot table, the foreign and local key have to be added, for the setup doesn't follow the eloquent conventions. That's fine, as long as you give laravel the information it needs. As a good practice, I use to create the reverse relationship too. In Staff.php model add the relationship to vehicles() return $this->belongsToMany(Vehicle::class, 'vehicle_staffs', 'staffs_id', 'vehicles_id');

Comment: thank you for great answer. for add $vehicle->staff()->attach($staffIds); fine. can you explain update case.

Comment: continue to read the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) and you should see  `Syncing Associations`, use `sync` instead of `attach` should update many-to-many relationships

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Laravel you are using, so I assume you are on Laravel 5.x.

You should probably use [saveMany()](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_saveMany) if you want to save more than one object. It takes a Collection or an array of Models as a parameter.

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method):

> If you need to save multiple related models, you may use the saveMany method:
>
> ```
> $post = App\Post::find(1);
>
> $post->comments()->saveMany([
>     new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
>     new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
> ]);
> ```